# Issue in adding and removing rows dynamically in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to add and remove rows in LWC, but every time when I click the tile it just add two tiles of that in another component.

So every time when I click on the second tile it just losing its first record Id.
How would I achieve that when I click on the second picture then it should be in the second row.

```
  @api recordId;

  @api objectRecordId;

  selectedName;

  productName;
  productPrice;
  productInfo;
  productImage;
  noOfProducts = 0;
  totalCost = 0;
  pricebookEntryId;
  prodId;
  tempProdId;

  subscription;
  addUserModal = false;

  keyIndex = 0;
  @track itemList = [
    {
      recordId: 0
    }
  ];
    connectedCallback() {
    this.subscription = subscribe(
      this.messageContext,
      PRODUCT_SELECTED_MESSAGE,
      (message) => this.handleProductSelected(message.productId)
    );
  }
    handleProductSelected(productId) {
    var cartObj = {};
    var objOfCartObj = {};
    var newItem = [];
    this.recordId = productId;
    getProductInfo({ recordId: this.recordId }).then((data) => {
      this.productInfo = data;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.productInfo.length; i++) {
        this.productImage = this.productInfo[0].Product2.Picture_URL__c;
        this.productName = this.productInfo[0].Product2.Name;
        this.productPrice = this.productInfo[0].UnitPrice;
        this.pricebookEntryId = this.productInfo[0].Id;
        this.prodId = this.productInfo[0].Product2Id;
      }
      this.totalCost = this.totalCost + this.productPrice;
      
      if(this.keyIndex == 0){
        this.keyIndex++;
        newItem = [{ recordId: this.keyIndex }];
        this.noOfProducts = this.noOfProducts + 1;
      }
      if(this.tempProdId == this.prodId){
        this.noOfProducts = this.noOfProducts + 1;
        
      }
      if(this.tempProdId != null && this.tempProdId != this.prodId){
        newItem = [{ recordId: this.keyIndex }];
        this.itemList = this.itemList.concat(newItem);
        this.noOfProducts = this.noOfProducts + 1;
        this.keyIndex++;
      }
      this.tempProdId = this.prodId;
      
      cartObj = {
        productId: this.prodId,
        prodName: this.productName,
        prodPriceList: [
          {
            pricebookId: this.pricebookEntryId,
            productId: this.prodId,
            prodPrice: this.productPrice,
            qty: this.noOfProducts,
          },
        ],
      };
    });
  }
deleteRow() {
    
  }


<template>
<lightning-card icon-name="standard:checkout">
    <span slot="title">Cart</span>
    <template if:true={recordId}>
        <template for:each={itemList} for:item="item" for:index="index">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" key={recordId}>
            <div class="slds-col">
              <span>
                <img src={productImage} class="product slds-align_absolute-center" alt="Issue occured at our end, try refreshing your page"/>&nbsp;
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
              <span>
                X {noOfProducts}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
              <span>
                Price:&nbsp;
                <lightning-formatted-number
                    format-style="currency"
                    currency-code="USD"
                    value={productPrice}
                    class="price">
                </lightning-formatted-number>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>
                    <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:delete" variant="container" alternative-text="Delete" class="slds-m-left_xx-small" title="Delete" onclick={deleteRow} access-key={recordId} id={index}></lightning-button-icon>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </template>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
                <div class="slds-m-left_x-small">
                    <span>
                    <p>Total</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                <span>
                    <lightning-formatted-number
                        format-style="currency"
                        currency-code="USD"
                        value={totalCost}
                        class="price">
                    </lightning-formatted-number>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template if:false={recordId}>
        <p class="slds-align_absolute-center">Select a product to see details</p>
    </template>
</lightning-card>
<lightning-input type="text" value={tempProdId} class="slds-hide"></lightning-input>
```

Comment: `this.recordId = productId;`  will cause an exception because `recordId` is immutable. You need to keep your public properties separate from your private ones. Unfortunately, you have a lot of code here so I'm not sure if this will completely solve your problem - hence I'm not putting this as an answer.

Comment: So, what should I do? How would I separate this?

Comment: @H John, too much code, please provide a minimal reproduceable code sample.
quick tip, whatever you chose to display, store in a mutable property, where you can add/remove objects to display.

Comment: @glls I have removed unnecessary code.

Comment: @CasparHarmer  I have also tried with getter and setter methods as you have mentioned but I am getting the same result

Comment: So... at this point you need to open up the debugger and step through the code - you still have a lot there and there are potentially a lot of issues. If you could cut the code down to almost nothing, but still have the problem occur (reproducibility), that would be best for us to try to find the problem. All I can say is that the problem I suggested a fix for is real - but there are probably more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `recordId` to be set externally - and internally (using `@api`) - and I'm not sure you do, then you would generally use getter/setter combo and a private internal var. Eg:

```
_recordId
@api
get recordId() {
  return this._recordId;
}
set recordId(value) {
  this._recordId = value;
}
```

You would then use `this._recordId` for all other references to recordId.